# How to handle the MouseRightButtonDown Event for a Window in Silverlight OOB

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I want to disable Silverlight contex menu for a Window in Silverlight OOB application

```
Window wn = new Window();
```

`wn.Show();`

For ChildWindow in silverlight I was able to disable the silverlight default context menu which displays "Silverlight" and "Remove this Application" by handling its MouseRightButtonDownEvent

```
 ChilWindow.MouseRightButtonDownEvent +=(s,e)=>{e.handled=true;};
```

But I am not able to handle the default contex menu here because the Window class is missing the MouseRightButtonDownEvent
If I put a usercontrol inside the window i am able to handle it for the content inside the window however the contex menu is not disabled in the windows title bar.